# Infinite finitely generated $2$-groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can somebody give me an example of a finitely generated infinite $2$-group?

Comment: I've found this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigorchuk_group. Isn't there any simpler example?

Comment: I think that the Grigorchuk group is the "simplest" known example.